# Is there a structured data source containing information on the World Health Organisation's Stability Testing Policies?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, temperature, software, drugs, pharmacology

Hoping to automate some product testing guidance software, I've been attempting to find a (hopefully live, up-to-date) Database, Web-service, or other structured data source containing the pharmaceutical Stability Testing policies (zones/countries/conditions) held by the World Health Organization.  But so far, the only format that I can find these policies in is PDF (http://apps.who.int/medicinedocs/documents/s19133en/s19133en.pdf) which is difficult to interpret for my purposes (even more so to automate).

Could anyone confirm the existence or non-existence of a structured data source containing information regarding WHO policy Stability Testing Conditions, Zones and countries within each zone?

Comment: I don't know if you have tried, but this sort of question could potentially find an answer on the [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacology)